# Docker container with nginx exits with 127 immediately after start

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I use nginx and crated simple config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name my-address.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
  }
}
```

Also I use docker-compose and and configure nginx with it:

```
  nginx-server:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf.prod:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    command: service nginx start
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - front
```

I added to /etc/hosts 127.0.0.1 my-address.com

On docker-compose up docker builds nginx image and exits

```
nginx exited with code 127
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you override the normal nginx start command (`CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`)?

Comment: @HansKilian I dont have separate dockerfile for nginx and wanted to specify all start comands in one file. but thank you for this question - I removed this command and without it I get:
 [crit] 1#1: pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf" failed (21: Is a director
 [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)

Comment: That looks like /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf inside the container is a directory. It should be a file. Is ./nginx/nginx.conf.prod the file you've posted?

Comment: @HansKilian you are right, there is error in path, I fixed it and get another error
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "frontend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:8

Comment: @HansKilian found problem - forgot to add hostname for frontend in docker-compose. thank you for hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exits with code 127 because there is no command called `service`. If you run docker-compose attached to your shell, (without the `-d` option) you can see the output:

```
$ docker-compose up
Recreating nginx ... done
Attaching to nginx
nginx           | /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 38: service: not found
nginx exited with code 127
```

You should remove the line

```
command: service nginx start
```

from your docker-compose file and use the default command which is already in the image.